# Can equality (=) be defined through a set of axioms similarly to how natural numbers can be defined through Peano axioms?

Tags: number-theory

Peanos axioms provide a way to describe and construct a set of natural numbers without ever mentioning numbers or their properties (+, -, next, etc...). Can the same, or something similar, be done with the idea of equality?

Comment: Do you mean "[*Peano*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms)"? If so (and if not, what do you mean?), in what sense don't those axioms mention numbers and their properties?  (That said you may be interested in the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907328/why-do-the-axioms-of-equality-suffice).)

Comment: @user953376 I've never studied logic at that level.  Out of curiosity, what's the first order phrasing for equivalence?

Comment: Yes. All mathematics can be done in a suitable foundational system, such as the Fitch-style system at "[Predicate logic: How do you self-check the logical structure of your own arguments?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681857/predicate-logic-how-do-you-self-check-the-logical-structure-of-your-own-argumen)". As with all Fitch-style systems, it has the rules **=intro** and **=elim** that govern equality. In fact, Peano Arithmetic relies on those as well; it is wrong to think that Peano managed to describe natural numbers without equality.